# How to use an HTML variable in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to use an HTML variable `src` in JavaScript this way:

```
<iframe id="myFrame" style="display:none" width="600" height="300"></iframe>

<input type="button" value="PDF 1" id="src"
   onclick="openPdf()" src="https://drive.google.com/" /> 
<input type="button" value="PDF 2" id="src"
   onclick="openPdf()" src="https://drive.google.com/" />
<input type="button" value="PDF 3" id="src"
   onclick="openPdf()" src="https://drive.google.com/"/>

<script type="text/javascript">
function openPdf() {
   var omyFrame = document.getElementById("myFrame");
   omyFrame.display = "hidden"; // 1
   omyFrame.style.display="block";
   omyFrame.src = "https://drive.google.com/"; // 2
}
</script>
```

1. I am not sure if this is working. If i press on pdf file 2 then if some other pdf file is alreasdy open, it should close and then "PDF 2" should open. In short, only one pdf file should open at a time and other pdf file should close or hide but all the buttons should be visible.
2. It is working but I have to repeate the code in every button. I want to change this constant address with a variable and i want to mention the address of pdf file in the buttons as above `src=`. so that i don't have to repeat the fuction inside every button.

Comment: Typo mistake in attr `scr`

Comment: It would be better to put your question(s) into words instead of just pasting the source code and let the community fix it.

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to read anything from the HTML, if you use [JavaScript Function Parameters](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_function_parameters.asp).

```
<iframe id="myFrame" style="display:none" width="600" height="300"></iframe>

<input type="button" value="PDF 1" onclick="openPdf('https://example.com/pdf1.pdf')" />
<input type="button" value="PDF 2" onclick="openPdf('https://example.net/pdf2.pdf')" />
<input type="button" value="PDF 3" onclick="openPdf('https://example.com/pdf3.pdf')" />
    
<script type="text/javascript">
  function openPdf(url) {
    var omyFrame = document.getElementById("myFrame");
    omyFrame.style.display="block";
    omyFrame.src = url
  }
</script>
```

You may also want to hide the `<iframe>` again, if the parameter is not set or is empty:

```
<iframe id="myFrame" style="display:none" width="600" height="300"></iframe>

<input type="button" value="PDF 1" onclick="openPdf('https://example.com/pdf1.pdf')" />
<input type="button" value="PDF 2" onclick="openPdf('https://example.net/pdf2.pdf')" />
<input type="button" value="PDF 3" onclick="openPdf('https://example.com/pdf3.pdf')" />
<input type="button" value="HIDE 1" onclick="openPdf('')" />    
<input type="button" value="HIDE 2" onclick="openPdf()" />

<script type="text/javascript">
  function openPdf(url) {
    var omyFrame = document.getElementById("myFrame");
    if (typeof url !== 'undefined' && url != '') {
       omyFrame.style.display="block";
       omyFrame.src = url
    } else {
       omyFrame.style.display="none";
    }
  }
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can get `clicked` `element` with `event.target`. And to get value of its `attribute` you can use `getAttribute('scr')`. So to get your desired value you can use `var scr = event.target.getAttribute('scr');`.

I have removed `id` from every `input` as it was not in any use. Also corrected typo from `scr` with correct `src`.

As per suggestion from [@tevemadar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63170624/how-to-use-html-variable-in-javascript/63170940?noredirect=1#comment111707625_63170940) adding `event` to `onclick="openPdf(event)"` instead of using directly in code.

Try it below.

```js
function openPdf(e) {
  var src = e.target.getAttribute('src');
  console.log(src);
  // your code
}
```

```html
<input type="button" value="PDF File 1" onclick="openPdf(event, this)" src="https://drive.google.com/" /></br>
<input type="button" value="PDF File 2" onclick="openPdf(event)" src="https://google.com/" /></br>
<input type="button" value="PDF File 3" onclick="openPdf(event)" src="https://stack.com/" />
```

Comment: @Karan: you should not use `event` this way (via [`Window`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/event)), consider adding them to the `openPdf()` calls instead. Also the repeated and unused `id="src"`-s could be removed.

Answer (score 1):

You don't even need JavaScript, just use an anchor with myframe specified as `target`. Obviously, CORS should be enabled, or this wont work.

If you want, you can style the anchor as a button using CSS.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>

<a href="https://example.com/pdf1.pdf" target="myframe" rel="noreferrer noopener">Click here</a>

<iframe name="myframe" width=500 height=500></iframe>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: @EsaJokinen Well, it's not very clear what the actual question really was, but it wasn't about showing an iframe. One could still add that to my example.

Comment: The iframe initially being `display:none` and the JS changing it to `display:block` is an indicator that's an intended function, but the question could have stated the desired functionality more clearly. It would be nice, though, if you could demonstrate a solution without JS, possibly using HTML5.

Comment: @EsaJokinen I read it as 'how can I pass a variable to an event handler', but it's just a guess ;-). I don't think that what you want be done without JS, but feel free to ask a separate question. I guess I wouldn't set a fixed style on the iframe initially, but use JS to hide it (and show it again in the anchor's click handler). If JS is somehow not available, it will still kind of work.

Comment: Well, I wouldn't even use an iframe in the first place but simply link to the PDF files. :)

Comment: @EsaJokinen Even better! Please tell OP that :-)

Answer (score -2):

No, unfortunately, you can't put a dynamic variable in it.

You can get the `id` inside the function to see which button is pressed, and write different `src` accordingly.